# VS Code Extension - Best approach for extending JSON

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking into what would be the best option to extend VS code with an extension which add some more features to the JSON Format such as additional keyword highlighting.

What would be the best approach ?

- Taking over the tmlanguage file for JSON and add additional options for eg syntax highlighting connected to a new language ?
- "Extending" the JSON fomat ?
- Custom linter ?

This looks my best bet I could find till now: [Can a language in Visual Studio Code be extended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723181/can-a-language-in-visual-studio-code-be-extended)

Tnx in advance for giving advice what would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what features do you want and how much time you would like to spend on it.

If the syntax highlighting is the main purpose, just get a tmLanguage file for the programming language and use the official generator [yocode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/yocode) to create an extension from it.

Visual Studio Code and Microsoft behind it are promoting the [Language Server Protocol](https://langserver.org) which may be the ultimate solution. And of course, it requires much more work.

Comment: Tnx a lot for the info ! Think i will start with a tmLanguage file to have something up and running more quickly. And in 2nd phase have a look into the anguage Server protocol.